# Grainy EPS Figures in PDF

Tags: lyx, pdf, eps

When exporting to PDF, my EPS figures (graphs created in EViews) have white vertical lines running through them (see below) - although these disappear when I zoom in and in print.

Could someone help me solve this problem?

I am currently using Lyx and Adobe/Sumatra PDF viewers.

Thanks

Link to EPS file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yliz64rrgyqhg0/alt_var.pdf?dl=0

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it would be useful for us to see such eps files as we might not be familiar with EViews (I've never heard of it). (3) it is most likely due to rounding errors when displaying the image on screen as you have already noticed they disappear when you zoom in

Comment: @ts_highbury I suppose that the white lines are due to the rasterization effect by your PDF viewer, and IMO I think that it will not be present when you take a printout of the document. Moreover, did you try printing your document with this figure on it?

Comment: @ts_highbury I've seen this with some other programs, like IgorPro versions older than 7, too. Can EViews save in any other format? SVG? Directly PDF? Can you at least upload some minimal EPS (zoom-in of the region between 3 and 6) showing this?

Comment: @RaajaG there is no problem with the print out, just viewing the files in Adobe and Sumatra

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I have added a link to the EPS file. I have tried saving in PDF as well, but the problem persists

Comment: @ts_highbury Then it's the problem that usually happens (for myself as well from Matlab 2014b) due to the PDF trying to display the figure by using its internal rasterization, to be honest, I don't know how to solve this. As far as I don't affect your printed documents, then I suppose the job is done :)

Comment: I feared that would be the answer. I'd like to get it sorted as I will submit a PDF version as a working paper which will be viewed online

Comment: @ts_highbury Ohh, from my experience, as a reviewer I prefer to review a manuscript in a printed format. So, I hope that will not be a problem for you.

Comment: @ts_highbury I only see the artifacts in your pdf when turning on the "smooth line art" option in acrobat reader options. Makes me think this is an aliasing problem. I don't see the lines in evince/Linux, even though that used be a huge issue for me a few years back. The lines are there in Inkscape. Can you use any other kind of shading? Darker, patterned?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Thanks for your help. The lines disappear when I deslect "smooth line" art in acrobat reader. However, presumably others who have not deselected this option will see the lines even if I can't.

Comment: @ts_highbury I've just checked the file in Inkscape. Looks like your program saves those problematic trapezoids as two: the top one is filled but has no stroke paint, then the same one underneath has stroke color set, and no filling. Shouldn't be too hard to fix in Inkscape (select the elements with F2 tool, change colors appropriately).